# SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Tags: java, oracle, sqlexception

I've made certain jtextfield, jRadioButtons, and some text areas. I want them to insert to data entered in these SQL Database. I've made the following code:

```
Connection conn = null;
    //Statement stm = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "hr", "hr");
        System.out.println("Driver Connected.");
        pst=conn.prepareStatement("insert into directorsdb (DIRECTOR_NAME, DOB, DIN, PAN, UIN, BIRTH_PLACE, PASSPORT, DRIVING_LIC, NATIONALITY, OCCUPATION, OCCUPATION_COMPANY, DESIGNATION, QUALIFICATION, ADDRESS_OFF, ADDRESS_RESI, CONTACT_HOME, CONTACT_WORK, CONTACT_MOBILE, EMAIL_PERSONAL, EMAIL_WORK, EMAIL_OTHER, SECRETARY_NAME, SECRETARY_CONTACT, SECRETARY_EMAIL, DSC, DSC_EXPIRY, FATHER_NAME, MOTHER_NAME, APPOINTMENT_DATE, POSITION_BOARD, CESSATION_DATE, CESSATION_REASON, PROMOTER, INDEPENDENT_DIRECTOR, ABOUT)"
                                  + "values("+jFormattedTextField1.getText()+"','"+jDateChooser1.getDate()+"','"+DIN.getText()+"','"+PAN.getText()+"','"+UIN.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField4.getText()+"','"+passportno.getText()+"','"+dlicense.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField5.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField6.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField7.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField8.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField9.getText()+"','"+officeadd.getText()+"','"+residentialadd.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField12.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField13.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField14.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField15.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField16.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField17.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField18.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField19.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField20.getText()+"','"+buttonGroup1.getSelection().getActionCommand()+"','"+jDateChooser2.getDate()+"','"+jFormattedTextField22.getText()+"','"+jFormattedTextField23.getText()+"','"+jDateChooser3.getDate()+"','"+jFormattedTextField25.getText()+"','"+jDateChooser4.getDate()+"','"+jTextArea2.getText()+"','"+buttonGroup2.getSelection().getActionCommand()+"','"+buttonGroup3.getSelection().getActionCommand()+"','"+jTextArea1.getText()+"',')");

        pst.execute();

        if(pst.execute()==true){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Saved Successfully!!");   
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Saved Successfully!!");
        }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
     catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
         System.err.println(ex);
     }
```

The exception I'm getting is:

```
SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

Help me in rectifying the same.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the opening ' char for the first value.

Comment: Try to store your SQL in a String and get the value of that variable during Debug and then try it in your Oracle database to see more clearly your error. Your SQL is too long thus it would be advisable to put in a variable for easier debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You have more values provided than the column count in your SQL.

When using PrepareStatement, please use place holder in the SQL to avoid SQL injection.

```
String selectSQL = "SELECT USER_ID, USERNAME FROM DBUSER WHERE USER_ID = ? and NAME = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setInt(1, 1001);
preparedStatement.setString(2, "test");
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

When it is update:

```
String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE DBUSER SET USERNAME = ? WHERE USER_ID = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "value");
preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1001);

preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```